# SQL on how to list of customers who have placed more than 30 orders in a single year

Tags: sql

```
select CustomerKey, FirstName, LastName
from DimCustomer
where CustomerKey in
    (select distinct CustomerKey
     from FactInternetSales
     where year(OrderDate) = 2005 or year(OrderDate) = 2006
        or year(OrderDate) = 2007 or year(OrderDate) = 2008);
```

Where am I supposed to add 'more than 30 orders' section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below by using join and aggregation filter

```
select DimCustomer.CustomerKey,
 DimCustomer.FirstName, DimCustomer.LastName,year(FactInternetSales.OrderDate),count(*)
from DimCustomer join FactInternetSales
 on DimCustomer.CustomerKey=FactInternetSales.CustomerKey
group by CustomerKey, FirstName, LastName,year(FactInternetSales.OrderDate)
having count(*)>=30
```

Comment: select C.CustomerKey,
 FirstName, LastName, year(FIS.OrderDate), count(*)
from [dbo].[DimCustomer] as C inner join [dbo].[FactInternetSales] as FIS
 on C.CustomerKey=FIS.CustomerKey
group by C.CustomerKey, FirstName, LastName,year(FIS.OrderDate)
having count(*)>=30         This is how I fixed it based on my database.

Comment: @user11007886 that means my query helps to you right?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work, but you need `group by`, not `select distinct`:

```
select c.CustomerKey, c.FirstName, c.LastName
from DimCustomer c
where c.CustomerKey in (select fis.CustomerKey
                        from FactInternetSales fis
                        where fis.OrderDate >= '2005-01-01' and
                              fis.OrderDate < '2009-01-01'
                        group by year(fis.OrderDate)
                        having count(*) >= 30
                       );
```

Use the `where` clause in the subquery if you want to limit the result to a particular time period.